# Maven Servlet Dependency For Wildfly 19.1.0

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, java-ee-8

I have build a small "Dynamic Web Project" in Eclipse, and have successfully used it to package a .WAR file and deploy it to a Wildfly 19.1.0 server. In order to do this I used Eclipse to add the Wildfly server's context to the project.

Now I am trying to use Apache Maven to package the .WAR file. I think the Wildfly BOM is where the dependency context would come from, and I can use the BOM to get the DMR dependency to stop throwing errors. However, I have a bunch of errors that read something like: *package javax.servlet does not exist* and *javax.servlet.annotation does not exist*. So I need to know how to add the servlet dependency to my **pom.xml**.

My .POM file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyToy</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyToy</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>MyToyApp</name>
  
  <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools</artifactId>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
      <version>19.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-dmr</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.20</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Does anybody know what I need to add to get servlets working?

I am unclear on where the list of dependencies would be that I can add to the pom.xml which I don't need a version for when I add the BOM. I have tried to find a list for those, so if it exists that would be helpful.

I also have not other Maven setup than the pom.xml, so if I am missing a step that would be helpful to know as well.

Comment: Have a look at the helloworld quickstart, https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/20.0.0.Final/helloworld/pom.xml#L61-L66.

Comment: Thanks that was a big help. It took me a while to realized I needed the jboss-parent as well, which required a newer version of mvn than yum provided. Not sure the protocol here, but if you put that in an answer I would mark it correct to close this out.

Answer (score 0):

In maven pom file you failed to define dependencies as mentioned below,

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-jsp-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>
```